# Rotating Swashplate on Piston Pump

Tags: pumps

A piston pump has a swash plate that pivots back and forth to control the flow rate of the hydraulic fluid.

Is there a version of this pump where the swash plate rotates like a cam instead of the pistons rotating?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: And it's called? Can I buy it on ebay?

Comment: Related - https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28732/swash-plate-pump-design?rq=1

Comment: Well, just rotating swash plate, I'm not an English speaker, but we call it the same in German and French. Can you buy it on eBay !!! I'll spend much more consideration on buying underwear, than you spend on buying pump, assuming you haven't done any research before, and no I don't trust eBay even with my underpants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two categories of pumps with non-orbiting pistons:

1. Axial piston pumps with rotating swash plate.
   Operating principle at 0:48 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP3gc4b8Z5k
   Commercial examples:
   Dynex Rivett PFXXXX and PVXXXX series
   Oilgear PFBX and PFCX series
2. Radial piston pumps.
   Operating principle at 0:15 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2T-6jDm_ebI
   Commercial examples:
   Bosch-Rexroth PR4-XX series
   HYDAC HRK series
   HAWE R series

Need more info about inlet/outlet pressure, flow, temperature, working fluid, noise limits, motor speed/power/torque, geometric constraints, etc... to recommend a specific pump.

Comment: A Checkball Piston pump! Yes! 5 years of searching and I have a name!

Comment: What's the application you plan to use it for? Checkball pumps are incredibly durable, but are usually overkill for most hydraulic systems. They are about 5x more expensive than the same size conventional pump.

Comment: It's experimental. I am wondering if precision hydraulics can be achieved if the pump delivered a smooth continuous pressure without those pressure spikes and troughs. To that end, I need to make a piston pump that is easy to build (partially 3d printed) but delivers a good working pressure and flow. I've built a peristaltic and a scotch yoke pump but they both had a lot of "pulses" in their pressure output.

Comment: The checkball pumps and radial piston pumps will have similar pressure spikes compared with standard axial piston pumps. 

The key variable is the number of pumping chambers. More chambers = smoother pressure output. I've seen checkball pumps with up to 10 chambers, and radial piston pumps with up to 9 chambers. 

The smoothest pump available is a screw pump, although pressure is limited to about 1500 psi even in the best cases. Some gear and vane type pumps achieve very low ripple. 

Any of the above should be much better than a peristaltic or yoke-type pump.